# how get dependent dropdown data in node with postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I have done following thing, using nodejs exoress with postgresql. For this api my input will be country id, modelname of country & for left join another model name im

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "module": "state_master",
  "leftJoinmodule": "country_master"
}
```

```
exports.getStateDataByCountryId = async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.module) {
    return response.fail(res, "Model Name is Required", "");
  }
  const id = req.body.id;
  var module = req.body.module;
  var leftJoinmodule = req.body.leftJoinmodule;
  console.log(leftJoinmodule)
  if (Model[module]) {
    Model[module]
      .findAll({
        raw: true,
        where: {
          country_id: id,
          active: 1,
        },
        include: [{
          model: Model.leftJoinmodule,
          as: 'country'
        },]

        // include: [{
        //   model: Model.leftJoinmodule,
        //   as: 'country',
        //   where: {
        //     id: id
        //   }
        // }]
      })
      .then((allStateMasterData) => {
        return response.success(res, "All State Data", allStateMasterData);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return response.catchError(res, err.message, "", module);
      });
  } else {
    return response.fail(res, "Invalide Model Name", "");
  }
};
```

getting below error

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "code": 0,
    "message": "Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.",
    "data": ""
}
```

anyone plz help on this issue